# Android 4.0.3 getting local IP

Tags: android, wifi

I have problem with android 4.0.3. I'm using the method below to get local IP:

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
try {
    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
        NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
        for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
            InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
            if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

It works great on android v2.1-2.3. But on emulator with android 4.0.3 it returns something like mac-address: fe80::fad0:bdff:fe4d:4871 Can anyone explain what's happened?

Comment: Check  if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && !isIPV6(inetAddress))

Comment: How can I convert it to IPv4?

Comment: I dont think you can convert an address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only the IPv4 address, change

```
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
```

to

```
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address)) {
```

Comment: Incompatible conditional operand types InetAddress and Inet4Address

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using [`getAllByName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName%28java.lang.String%29).

As I mentioned , the address you are getting is an IPv6 address & you cant convert an IPv6 address to an IPv4 address.